# Crystal report in not showing the data at Second Run

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm new to crystal report. When i try to execute one of my crystal report with some selection, it showing the data. But at second run without changing any selection that report showing blank only with headers. No error is showing against it. I'm getting same data at data table at second run. But it is showing blank report. Can anyone tell me how to fix this problem? Here I'm attaching first run and second run.
[This is the screen of crystal report after First run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEOMZ.png)

[This is after second run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8r67n.png)

This is the View Report method calling on execution. I'm running same type two times. First time it showing all data properly.

```
public void viewreport()
        { 
            createreport();
            crystalReportViewer1.ShowRefreshButton = false;
            
            if (boolPrintOption == false)
            {
                if (cmbReportType.SelectedIndex == 1)
                {
                    if (cmbCategory.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        if (this.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                            {
                                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report_FixedDetails;
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report_FixedDetails;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (this.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                            {
                                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report_FlxyMibcoDetail;
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report_FlxyMibcoDetail;
                        }
                    }

                }
               
                else 
                {
                    if (cmbCategory.SelectedIndex == 0)
                    {
                        if (this.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                            {
                                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report_FixedSummary;
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report_FixedSummary;
                        }
                    }
                   else
                    {
                        if (this.InvokeRequired)
                        {
                            this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
                            {
                                crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report_FlxyMibcoSummary;
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report_FlxyMibcoSummary;
                        }
                    }
                }
                

                if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 0)
                {
                    clsTVD6Message objMsg = new clsTVD6Message();
                    objMsg.ShowMessage("SAV6056");
                    return;
                }
            }
          
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Dataset or Report Object it, make Null, mean empty for next run